# Installation problem because of updation problem

Tags: apt, server, updates

I can't not able to update it give me 5 errors
Output:

```
Err:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 40.65.182.21 80]
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
403 Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
```

Comment: Works for me. The `403` http error suggests that you might have some network problem. Perhaps you are behind a proxy on some enterprise network?